# Access pass a Form Variable to SQL command

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to select a predefined number of random records (with seed) from a table.

I have written the following but it does not work

```
SELECT TOP ([Forms]![Form1]![NumerofElements]) *
FROM TableA
ORDER BY Rnd(-(100000*ID)*[Forms]![Form1]![Seed])
```

Do you have any idea on how I can pass directly in SQL those information that are reported in a Form (`Form1`)?

Comment: You can't dynamically change the `TOP` amount like that as far as I know. It needs to be hardcoded into the query. You can use VBA to modify the query, though.

Answer (score 0):

No. TOP doesn't take a parameter.

You can create a query using this SQL:

```
Sql = "SELECT TOP {0} * FROM TableA ORDER BY Rnd(-Timer()*[ID])"
```

and then use replace:

```
YourQuery.SQL = Replace(Sql, "{0}", ([Forms]![Form1]![NumerofElements]))
```

and then use the query.

Comment: I'd also wrap `[Forms]![Form1]![NumerofElements]` in a `CInt` function to prevent possible SQL injection. Unfortunately, you can't use parameters here

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: Good idea.

Comment: I need to put both the two lines in the VBA editor? And then how can I call the query? Moreover, it says that it cannot find 'Form1' even if that exists. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should use the query as you did before. And the form has to be open for the code to run.